# Views Slideshow only displaying first slide in IE

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have Views Slideshow working fine on Chrome 24.0.1312.56 m, and Firefox 18.0.1. But for some reason Views Slideshow only display the first slide (of five) in IE9.

I'm using Views Slideshow 7.x-3.0, Views Slideshow Cycle 7.x-3.0 and my jQuery.cycle file is version 2.9999.81. I also have "JavaScript Aggregation" turned OFF.

Like I said, the slider has no issues in Chrome, or Firefox, only IE9 where it will display the first slide and then just blank space for the other slides. The preview of the View works in IE, but then no longer works when you save the View.

*EDIT*
I found something interesting. It looks like IE is not giving the other slides div-container any width or height? I've attached a picture:

[image: snap]

Comment: Does IE9 spit out any errors into alerts or console? Have you checked changing the compatibility mode in IE just for testing purposes?

Comment: In admin/config/development/performance do you have aggregate  javascript? if  you have unchecked and save it. And then check it again.

Comment: I tried enabling compatibility mode to no avail, and I also tried checking and re-unchecking the javascript aggregation.

Comment: I found something interesting though, it looks like IE is not giving the other slides div-container any width or height? I've attached a picture to my first post.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1809568 Unfixed bug.

Comment: I've reviewed that thread before and almost everyone was complaining about issues with FF, not IE despite the bug thread title.

Comment: Not being a PHP-familiar programmer, I suppose aside from waiting for a patch or update... I've exhausted all my options?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a copy of drupal.org/node/1809568 bugreport.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `jquery.js` file by using [Jquery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module.

Comment: Using your suggestion, I updated my `jquery.js` file but the issue still persisted. You got me thinking that the error might be in my code, not in Views. After digging through my js files I pinpointed the cause. The [reflection.js](http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery) script I was using did not like to play nice with hidden divs in IE. I muddled through the comments and found a user who gave a code snippet to fix the hidden div display error. [Link to the comment](http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery#c001910)

Comment: @Matt - Consider posting a proper answer containing the information you've found. Don't worry, it's totally fine answering your own question and mark your answer as the correct answer. It'll save many other users finding your question a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this problem is solved in IE10 . I installed this module and tested it using IE10, there was no problem.